# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have created an angular 4 application and get the following error when I build it.

> "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

The supplied parameter and target method signature seem to be correct but not sure what the problem is.

Following is the code. Getting error at the line `this.movieService.getMovie`

```
public selectMovieId: number = 0;

setFormValues(){
    var existingMovie: IMovie;
    this.movieService.getMovie(this.selectMovieId).then((result: any)=> {
    existingMovie = result;
    this.movie = existingMovie;  
    });
```

Target Method

```
getMovie(movieId : number){
       return this._mrdbCommonService.httpGetByKey('/api/movies/{id}',movieId);
    }
```

httpGetByKey method

```
httpGetByKey(url: string, key: any) {
        return this.http.get(url + '/' + key, this.httpRequestOptions())
            .map((response: Response) => {
                this.storeRefreshToken(response.headers.get('refresh-token'));
                return response.json(); })
            .toPromise()
            .catch((error: any) => {
                this.onError(error);
                return Promise.reject(error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please use the [tag:angularjs] for version 1.x only (Already edited and removed that tag)

Comment: Post all the relevant code. And the exact and complete error message.

Comment: The code message is the complete one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. The actual error was in the Target method code where I was passing  {id} attribute in the URL  /api/movies/{id}.  It wasn't needed as httpGetByKey appends the key to it via the parameter.